# js async with proper error handling without await

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous

Can someone suggest to me how i can replicate this code with proper error handling without using await ?
I would like to run fnA/B/C asynchronously rather than sequentially with await, i would also like to handle all rejections to be handled in the main catch block.

Thanks

```
async function() {
  try {
    let a = await fnA();
    let b = await fnB();
    let c = await fnC();
    return(a+b+c);
  }
  catch(e) {
    e.exitCode === 'fnAError' ? doSomething : null;
    e.exitCode === 'fnBError' ? doSomething : null;
  }
}
```

**After all the suggestions this is what i ended up with:**

```
const caller = async () => {
  try {
    let promisePool = [];
    let a = await testA();
    let b = promisePool.push(testB()) - 1;
    let c = promisePool.push(testC()) - 1;

    let q = await Promise.all(promisePool);
    // Get all the non awaited values
    console.log(q[b]);
  }
  catch(e) {
    console.log('caller catch');
    console.log('ERROR: ' + e);
  }
}
```

**Thanks everyone**

Comment: Thanks everyone, looks like await Promise.all is what i was looking for!

Answer (score 2):

You have an AB problem.

If you want them to run in parallel instead of in series then the solution isn't to not use `await`, it is to use `Promise.all`.

```
try {
    let [a, b, c] = await Promise.all([fnA(), fnB(), fnc()]);
    return a + b + c;
}
```

You just need to await all the promises instead of each one in turn.

Comment: You might also show how this could be done without `await` since it isn't really necessary to a simple solution either.

Answer (score 0):

You can either combine `await` with `Promise.all()` like this:

```
async function() {
  try {
    const [a,b,c] = await Promise.all([fnA(), fnB(), fnC()]);
    return(a + b + c);
  }
  catch(e) {
    e.exitCode === 'fnAError' ? doSomething : null;
    e.exitCode === 'fnBError' ? doSomething : null;
    throw e;
  }
}
```

Or, you can use `.then()` and `.catch()` instead:

```
async function() {
    return Promise.all([fnA(), fnB(), fnC()]).then(([a, b, c]) => {
        return a + b + c;
    }).catch(err => {
        e.exitCode === 'fnAError' ? doSomething : null;
        e.exitCode === 'fnBError' ? doSomething : null;
        throw e;
    });
}
```

Note, if you're trying to return the modified error object to the caller of this function (still as a rejection), you need to rethrow the error after modifying it.